# Symlink - Permission Denied

Tags: linux, permissions, symlink, slackware

I'm facing an interesting problem with plenty of Permission Denied outputs when using SymLinks

Linux: Slackware 13.1

Directory with Symlink:

```
root@Tower:/var/lib# ls -lah
drwxr-xr-x  8 root       root    0 2012-12-02 20:09 ./
drwxr-xr-x 15 root       root    0 2012-12-01 21:06 ../
lrwxrwxrwx  1 ntop       ntop   21 2012-12-02 20:09 ntop -> /mnt/user/media/ntop6/
```

Symlinked Directory:

```
root@Tower:/mnt/user/media# ls -lah
drwxrwx--- 1 nobody users  1.4K 2012-12-02 19:28 ./
drwxrwx--- 1 nobody users   128 2012-11-18 16:06 ../
drwxrwxrwx 1 ntop   ntop    320 2012-12-02 20:22 ntop6/
```

What I have done:

- I have used chown -h ntop:ntop on the ntop directory in  /var/lib
- Just to be sure, I have chmod 777 to both directories

**Permission denied actions:**

```
root@Tower:/var/lib# sudo -u ntop mkdir /var/lib/ntop/test
mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/lib/ntop/test': Permission denied
```

Any ideas?

Comment: May I ask the output of "mount"?

Comment: Thanks Eric: /dev/md1 on /mnt/user type reiserfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,user_xattr,acl)

Comment: Is this because the thing that is mounted is read only? ie a DVD drive, or read-only nfs mount, etc/

Answer (score 4):

Unless ntop is a member of users, he cannot enter /mnt/user or /mnt/user/media, as entering a directory requires +x permissions.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. But I still get the following errors:   Dec  2 21:17:50 Tower ntop[13952]:   **WARNING** INIT: Unable to create pid file (/var/lib/ntop/ntop.pid)   Dec  2 21:18:00 Tower ntop[13952]:   **ERROR** RRD: Disabled - unable to create base directory (err 13, /var/lib/ntop/rrd)

Comment: That has nothing to do with the above. Please include the output of `namei -m /var/lib/ntop` with your question.